# Merging two lists using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to merge every other element of 2 lists with different lengths into one list. I am not allowed to use the built-in function `zip` and must use recursion.

From `print(zippa([1, 3, 5], [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]))` the result should be:  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]`.

This is my code so far:

```py
def zippa(l1, l2): 
    if len(l1) == 0:
        return l2[0] + zippa(l1,l2[1:])
    elif len(l2) == 0:
        return l1[0] + zippa(l1[1:],l2)
    elif len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return zippa(l1[1:0],l2) + zippa(l1,l2[1:0])
```

I don't understand how to get the values back into a list.
Does the order of the `elif` and such matter?

Comment: In general, yes, the order of if/elif/elif/else matters; although in some cases if the conditions are disjoint, it might not matter. In your case, it matters and the third branch (i.e. the second `elif`) will never be reached, because if the condition `len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0` was true, then the condition of the first branch `len(l1) == 0` would be true too, so the first branch would be picked (because it's first).

Comment: You need to return a list. That means that **every** value that follows the `return` keyword should be a list. You have a `return 0` in your code: that means that in some cases you might return 0, which is not a list. So this is bad; all `return` should be followed by a list. For the recursive calls, it's okay: if `zippa(l1[1:0],l2)` is a list and `zippa(l1,l2[1:0])` is a list, then `+` works on lists and `zippa(l1[1:0],l2) + zippa(l1,l2[1:0])
` will be a list too.

Comment: The first branch `if len(l1) == 0: return l2[0] + zippa(l1,l2[1:])` is not very logical. This is the case where `len(l1) == 0` is empty; yet you still pass `l1` to a recursive call `zippa(l1,l2[1:])`. If you know that `l1` is empty, then get rid of it!!!

Comment: The last branch `else: return zippa(l1[1:0],l2) + zippa(l1,l2[1:0])` has two issues. The first issue is that it doesn't progress with the work by itself, in addition to the recursive call. Remember we are trying to iterate through the elements in the lists. So ideally, you should do something with the first elements, then pass the remainder of the lists to the recursive call. But here you directly make the recursive calls, without doing anything with the first elements first.

Comment: @Stef all of those comments sound like an answer to me!

Comment: Could sum it up and post as the `answer`?

Comment: "I don't understand how to get the values back into a list. " I don't know which "values' you're talking about, and I don't know what you mean by "get back into". According to my best guess as to what the "values" are, they are already in lists the entire time.

Comment: But think carefully about your logic. Hint 1: look closely at the code `l2[0] + zippa(l1,l2[1:])`. It seems that you are confused about why this does not create a list where `l2[0]` is the first element and all the other elements come from `zippa(l1,l2[1:])`. But this is the same as it would be in any other context: try `'x' + ['y', 'z']`. What happens? Do you understand why? How would you fix this? If you don't know, then *that is your real question*, and *not anything to do with recursion*.

Comment: Hint 2: look closely at the code `return 0`. What is the *type* of the thing being returned? What is the type of thing that you are supposed to get from this overall process? Can you see why this would cause a problem? Sub-hint: what would happen if you wrote code to prepend an element to a list, but the "list" you received were actually an integer? Sub-hint: what kind of list can you create such that, when you prepend an element to it, you get a list with just that element?

Comment: @ggorlen I would answer, but you covered everything already ;)

Answer (score 4):

> I am not allowed to use the built-in function `zip` and must use recursion.

This is unfortunate. Your professor or instructor (apologies for the assumption that this is an academic project; if it's not, the same sentiment applies) is forcing you to misapply recursion. It's like trying to put out a fire with a bottle of champagne instead of a fire extinguisher. When you finish the class, please use a builtin and iteration!

Generally speaking, iteration is almost always the correct tool for operations on lists in Python. There are other problems where [recursion is actually suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842109/recursion-applied-to-lists-vs-trees-in-python/66846438#66846438), like traversing a tree, because the recursive step breaks the problem down by a sublinear factor. There's no dividing and conquering happening here.

Some reasons why recursion is a poor replacement for iteration:

- Every recursive call takes extra computational work to allocate and destroy call frames that loops don't.
- CPython has a recursion limit of around 1000 by default, so if your lists are longer than that (and they will be, for any nontrivial application), your program will crash. You can't indefinitely extend the call stack size, so [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) is an unsafe hack.
- Call frames don't share state with one another, so you're forced to do ugly things like add indexes to parameters or copy the *entire* list on every call with a slice (as you're doing), leading to unnecessary quadratic complexity at worst (as is the case here) or just awkward code (for example, if you want to build a result list, as is the case here).

[Some languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) support [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and are naturally suited to writing algorithms like this, but [Python isn't one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017621/why-isnt-python-very-good-for-functional-programming).

That said, I understand this is a pedagogical exercise, so let's play along and learn something about recursion.

---

I'd also like to offer a few general programming tips before diving in.

When you're stuck working on an algorithm, try simplifying the problem. See if you can merge two lists *of equal length*, then, once that's working, add the additional requirement of the lists being different lengths. This would eliminate checks for one list being empty and the other not and generally make the problem easier to grasp. When you go to tackle the full problem, you already have minimal working code for a subproblem and experience and patterns you've gained from solving issues in the smaller problem space.

The code here seems like you've jumped ahead, wrote it up without testing along the way, and have made a series of decisions and assumptions that don't make sense taken individually. Take smaller steps.

Print (or use a debugger) to inspect values at each frame. Work out the algorithm on small examples.

Essential reading: [Eric Lippert - How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

---

Let's inspect some of the small problems in the code and build up to the larger ones.

> Does the order of the `elif` and such matter?

If the branch conditions are all disjoint, then order doesn't matter, as in:

```py
if foo == "a": return 0
if foo == "b": return 1
if foo == "c": return 2
```

Since `foo` can't be `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` at the same time, these branches are mutually exclusive. This is a nice simplifying assumption when you can get it (the code above could be refactored to a table lookup, removing the conditional chain completely).

But if you have dependent checks like

```py
if len(l1) == 0:
    pass # l1 must be empty; l2 may or may not be
elif len(l2) == 0:
    pass # l2 must be empty and l1 is known to be nonempty
         # or the `len(l1) == 0` branch would have been taken
elif len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0:
    pass # unreachable, we've already covered cases
         # where one or the other was empty
```

then order does matter. The case when both are empty should be checked first (you can use simply `if lst:` and `if not lst:` to check their emptiness Pythonically).

Consider the cases when one of the lists is empty:

```py
if len(l1) == 0:
    return l2[0] + zippa(l1,l2[1:])
```

At this point, you can just `return l2` -- when one list is empty, all you need to do is return the nonempty one rather than chop it down piece-by-piece. Due to the order of your branches, `l2` isn't guaranteed to have an element -- it may well be empty.

Next, the code

```py
elif len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0:
    return 0 # ??!
```

has an inconsistent type. We're trying to return a list, so the base case of two empty lists is merged to one empty list, not the integer 0. This should be `return []` so the caller is using `+` on two lists to concatenate them, not `[] + 0`, which raises a TypeError. A typed language would not let you write this, and even in a dynamically-typed language, it's generally an antipattern to mix types even when it works.

In the primary recursive case code, the slice `l1[1:0]` always gives an empty list. Breaking the problem down to a small chunk and trying it in the repl to test our hypothesis, we see:

```py
>>> [1,2,3][1:0]
[]
```

Clearly, that's not what you intended. It looks like you're trying to encode the "alternation" pattern here, so you probably just wanted to chop off the first element as a list:

```py
>>> [1,2,3][0:1]
[1]
>>> [1,2,3][:1]
[1]
```

Secondly, it's not clear to me how the `zippa(l1[:1],l2) + zippa(l1,l2[:1])` pattern would work. We have an infinite loop because that first element will never be removed by any of the logic once it's there. Spawning more than 1 recursive call and merging the results isn't necessary for a linear list algorithm. It seems easiest to merge one of each of the elements from both lists in a single call -- there's no rule in recursion that says you can't.

Going back to the slicing, that's unnecessary quadratic complexity -- a lot of extra work just to shoehorn the algorithm to work recursively. We can solve both the complexity problem and the slicing problem by passing an index into the recursive calls as a third parameter. This could be a default parameter, or it can be added on an inner or helper function.

As a final optimization point that also makes the code simpler: every `+` operator on lists allocates a whole new list! If we do this on every frame, we're back to quadratic complexity. Merging lists must only involve a constant number of allocations (preferably one) if it's to be usable for any [nontrivial purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). This can be done by passing a single result list through the recursive calls, allocating it one time on the first call.

Here's the code:

```py
def merge_iterables(a, b, i=0, result=None): 
    if result is None:
        result = []

    if i < len(a) and i < len(b):
        result.append(a[i])
        result.append(b[i])
        merge_iterables(a, b, i + 1, result)
    else:
        result.extend(a[i:])
        result.extend(b[i:])

    return result
```

If you don't like exposing those parameters to the caller, use an inner or helper function, typical of recursion:

```py
def merge_iterables(a, b):
    result = []

    def merge(i=0):
        if i < len(a) and i < len(b):
            result.append(a[i])
            result.append(b[i])
            merge(i + 1)
        else:
            result.extend(a[i:])
            result.extend(b[i:])

    merge()
    return result
```

Note that although I'm slicing, it's in the one-off base case, so this is constant complexity (and one or both of the slices is empty anyway). You could use a traditional `range` loop to avoid these allocations, but that's a premature optimization.

---

Although it's not part of your assignment, an algorithm like this should generalize to any number of lists. This is easy by adding a loop:

```py
def merge_iterables(*its):
    result = []

    def merge(i=0):
        for x in its:
            if i < len(x):
                result.append(x[i])

        if any(i < len(x) for x in its):
            merge(i + 1)

    merge()
    return result
```

Time and space complexity here is O(nm).

Finally, [generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) are a Pythonic way to deal with iterable algorithms like this. `itertools` uses generators for everything, and it's good to follow suit. Generators give the caller maximum flexibility: they can use the same algorithm to merge, say, the first half of an iterable, or do it over time, lazily, in a memory-efficient manner (these use cases are part of the motivation why you want your algorithm to use constant space!)

```py
def merge_iterables(*its):
    def merge(i=0):
        for x in its:
            if i < len(x):
                yield x[i]

        if any(i < len(x) for x in its):
            yield from merge(i + 1)

    yield from merge()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(merge_iterables([1,2], [4,5,6,7], "a", "xyz")))
    # => [1, 4, 'a', 'x', 2, 5, 'y', 6, 'z', 7]
```

---

After all that, this is still a contrived and poor use case for recursion (try it on a 1000-element list if there's any lingering doubt), so you might want to see my suggested solution to the problem in the canonical thread [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion/69057908#69057908).

Let's [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit/62865237#62865237) some of the code in that answer along with the code in this answer and [the quadratic solution given in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69058378/6243352).

```py
import argparse
import copy
import dis
import inspect
import random
import sys
import timeit
from itertools import zip_longest

sys.setrecursionlimit(1350) # just for testing

def merge_pythonic(*its):
    return [x for y in zip_longest(*its) for x in y if x is not None]

def merge_iterables(*its):
    result = []

    def merge(i=0):
        for x in its:
            if i < len(x):
                result.append(x[i])

        if any(i < len(x) for x in its):
            merge(i + 1)

    merge()
    return result

def zippa(*its):
    if len(its) == 0:
        return []
    
    head_list, *rest_its = its
    
    if head_list:
        head, *rest = head_list
        return [head] + zippa(*rest_its, rest)
    else:
        return zippa(*rest_its)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--n", type=int, default=1300)
    parser.add_argument("--m", type=int, default=1300)
    parser.add_argument("--trials", type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument("--dis", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    n = args.n
    m = args.m
    trials = args.trials
    namespace = dict(its=[random.sample(range(n), k=n) for _ in range(m)])
    funcs_to_test = [x for x in locals().values() 
                     if callable(x) and x.__module__ == __name__]
    print(f"{'-' * 30}\nn = {n}, {trials} trials\n{'-' * 30}\n")

    for func in funcs_to_test:
        fname = func.__name__
        fargs = ", ".join(inspect.signature(func).parameters)
        stmt = f"{fname}({fargs})"
        setup = f"from __main__ import {fname}"
        time = timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=trials, globals=namespace)
        print(inspect.getsource(globals().get(fname)))

        if args.dis:
            dis.dis(globals().get(fname))

        print(f"time (s) => {'%.16f' % time}\n{'-' * 30}\n")
```

Even with the unfortunate restriction that we can't use larger tests than a thousand elements or so (argh! recursion!), the results are clear: the builtin smashes the recursive approaches, and quadratic doesn't scale as predicted, even on the tiny input (real-world iterables can often be hundreds of thousands, millions or billions of elements or more):

```
------------------------------
n = 1300, m = 1300, 1000 trials
------------------------------

def merge_pythonic(*its):
    return [x for y in zip_longest(*its) for x in y if x is not None]

time (s) => 0.4278396000000000
------------------------------

def merge_iterables(*its):
    result = []

    def merge(i=0):
        for x in its:
            if i < len(x):
                result.append(x[i])

        if any(i < len(x) for x in its):
            merge(i + 1)

    merge()
    return result

time (s) => 4.4487939000000001
------------------------------

def zippa(*its):
    if len(its) == 0:
        return []

    head_list, *rest_its = its

    if head_list:
        head, *rest = head_list
        return [head] + zippa(*rest_its, rest)
    else:
        return zippa(*rest_its)

time (s) => 40.0880948000000004
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

A classic way to handle recursion with lists is to split off the head of the list and then do something with the rest. This is a pattern you will see everywhere in functional languages the make recursion a first class citizen. It's not a first-class citizen in Python, but you can still use Python to learn these techniques.

Here we make a function that can zip any number of lists. This is handy, because once you exhaust the short list, you can continue calling it until there are no more lists without a lot of `if/else`.

```
def zippa(*lists):
    if len(lists) == 0:
        return []
    
    head_list, *rest_lists = lists
    
    if head_list:
        head, *rest = head_list
        return [head] + zippa(*rest_lists, rest)
    else:
        return zippa(*rest_lists)
    
print(zippa([1, 3, 5], [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]))
```

The only really complication in this assignment is that you are dealing with multiple lists. But the idea is the same, each call is responsible for taking the first list, then from the list take the first element. Then return that element with the result of recursion.

This works by rotating the lists as you recurse. By passing the rest of the original first list in last: `zippa(*rest_lists, rest)`.

This along with a well-chosen base case allows you to pass in any number of lists, which in turn makes the code simpler. You don't have to deal with indices or helper arguments.

```
# works with a single list
print(zippa([1, 3, 5]) )
# [1, 3, 5]

# or multiple:
print(zippa([1, 3, 5], [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0])) 
# [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```