# Discrepancy between system recursion depth and actual recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, sys

```
import sys

def Factorial(i):
    if i == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return i*Factorial(i-1)
    
sys.getrecursionlimit()

factorials = []
OOB = []

for i in range(1,3001):
    try:
        factorials.append(Factorial(i))
    except RecursionError:
        OOB.append(i)

print(OOB)
```

sys.getrecursionlimit() returns the max recursion depth as 3000. However, the function Factorial() returns a RecursionError for all i>29**84** [The list 'OOB' contained all  2985 ≤ i ≤ 3000]
As per the default system recursion depth, shouldn't the limit be till  i = 29**98** or i = 29**99** ?   Why is there a discrepancy here? If this question indicates a flaw in my understanding of recursion depth, please explain/guide to resources.

Comment: also by changing the recursion limit the new threshold value is not really respected. Don't know why

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  On my system, the limit is 1000 and this loop fails on i=999.

Comment: So, recursion limit is a bit misleading. It's really a stack limit. Recursive or otherwise. How exactly are you running this code? If, for example, you are using some tool as a part of our IDE, there may be a bigger stack to begin with

Comment: So, for eample, you have `sys.getrecursionlimit()` just sitting there, doing nothing. Are you running this in an IPython REPL by any chance? Or a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Apparently I have a similar system as @JohnGordon, plus I also tried calling `setrecursionlimit()`, which works until somewhere above 2400 (where I get a list of numbers starting with 2399), but below 2500 (where my Python 3.9.1 on 64-bit Windows simply dies and the list doesn't get printed).

Comment: Don't use recursion for linear stack depth algorithms and you'll (basically) never have any problem with this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66846438/6243352) for elaboration. Stack depth is a system-dependent factor that you shouldn't count on being set to a certain limit.

Comment: @cards It is respected when I run it on my system. Eg: setrecursionlimit(5000) allows the function to run up to i = 4984. The discrepancy is consistent though.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for indicating that it is a system specific limit.

Comment: @ggloren thanks for the link. Still don't fully understand how exactly the depth is calculated but I'm sure I'll find an explanation if I look in that direction.

Comment: @Jeril Philip have you tried with 50 or 80?